# Get locationwise post using facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to retrive the posts, or messsages for particular location using graph api in facebook.
At present I am using the below URL to find public posts, parameters are  access token, lat, long and buffer distance, but this url returns the all the posts irrespective of lat long and buffer distance https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=lunch&type=post&center=17,78&distance=100&access_token=xxxx

Please suggest me if any options available in graph api to fetch the post or messages for particular location